# Affine transform given 4 points

Tags: math, matrix, html5-canvas, affinetransform

How can I get a 3x3 matrix representing all the transformations (scale,rotation) to apply to an image drawn on a canvas given 4 points x1,y1...x4,y4 representing the ROI(sub-image) that I want to zoom and rotate on?

The first coordinates x1,y1 should be transformed to the top left corner(0,0) of the canvas and x2,y2 to the bottom right corner of the canvas(canvas.width, canvas.height).

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO can help you with the code wrote but SO will not write code for you.

Comment: I'm not asking for code. Just for the Formula because I'm not a math expert.

Comment: The canvas uses a 2*3 matrix and is set with `setTransform(a,b,c,d,e,f)`where `a`, `b` are the first row, `c`, `d` second and `e`, `f` the bottom row. Or you can think of it as 2 vectors and a coordinate `a`,`b` (î) the direction and scale of the x axis and `c`, `d` as the direction and scale of the y axis and `e`, `f` is the origin. All are in canvas coordinates.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Blindman67. My question is probably not clear enough. I'm actually trying to find the formula that will give me the rotation to apply to a given point (x1, y1) that will give it other coordinates (x2,y2). For example : 300, 0 becomes after rotation 0, 0 on a canvas 300, 300 = 90°. so 90°degree is unknown. Rotation axis is the center of the canvas.

Comment: You don't need to use four points with affine transformation, actually the fourth point could cause a problem unless it sits on an exact parallel distance. Using three points is sufficient - see [this source](https://github.com/epistemex/transformation-matrix-js/blob/master/src/matrix.js#L58) for formula.

Comment: Thank you K3N! That's what I was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

This function is actually quite useful. It is true that you *only* need 3 values. But, 4 is conceptually better since you're mapping one quadrilateral to another.

```py
def perspective(p1, p2, p3, p4):
        x1, y1 = p1
        x2, y2 = p2
        x3, y3 = p3
        x4, y4 = p4

        j = x1 - x2 - x3 + x4
        k = -x1 - x2 + x3 + x4
        l = -x1 + x2 - x3 + x4
        m = y1 - y2 - y3 + y4
        n = -y1 - y2 + y3 + y4
        o = -y1 + y2 - y3 + y4
        i = 1.0

        try:
            h = (j * o - m * l) * i / (m * k - j * n)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            h = 0

        try:
            g = (k * h + l * i) / j
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            g = 0

        f = (y1 * (g + h + i) + y3 * (-g - h + i)) / 2.0
        e = (y1 * (g + h + i) - y2 * (g - h + i)) / 2.0
        d = y1 * (g + h + i) - f - e
        c = (x1 * (g + h + i) + x3 * (-g - h + i)) / 2.0
        b = (x1 * (g + h + i) - x2 * (g - h + i)) / 2.0
        a = x1 * (g + h + i) - c - b
        return Matrix(a, d, b, e, c, f)
```

This is the mapping of [1, 1], [1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, 1] to the space given by P1, P2, P3, P4.

To make this really useful what you need is the even more helpful function of a mapping matrix:

```py
def map(p1, p2, p3, p4,  p5, p6, p7, p8):
        m1 = perspective(p1, p2, p3, p4)
        m2 = perspective(p5, p6, p7, p8)
        return ~m1 * m2
```

The `~` here means invert the matrix and the multiplication is matrix concatenation. This gives you the very useful function of mapping 4 points to 4 points. And solves for the matrix that makes that happen.

Now, a couple of notes. First, you can actually write this as an entire matrix. The 3x3 matrix we see for many transformations actually usually has a 3rd row that is `0,0,1` many system will give you a 3x2 matrix now, and this code here is dealing with affine matrices here which is the distinction.

When the `g, h, i` are equal to `0, 0, 1` the matrix is affine. If we have actual values for g and h these are sometimes called PERSPECTIVE_X and PERSPECTIVE_Y in some matrix formulations that list them out. The reason is they are only actually given values if the matrix is not affine, which is to say that parallel lines before the matrix is applied are still and parallel lines after the matrix is applied.

You can also actually use that additional set of values in a full 3x3 matrix, and it'll let you do perspective changes. So if you move a corner it will still solve for the full 3x3 matrix.

[image: pre-perspective matrix]

[image: post-perspective matrix]

This actually solves for the projection of the points from one space to the other space. If the transformation is affine you will get zeros for `g` and `h`.  If not you will get values there. This is still a regular transformation matrix and multiply your points by the matrix will give you the resulting points, but lines in that transformation may not remain parallel. However, if you mapped the first set of points to the second set of points such that they could *only* remain affine, this will just solve for the transformation matrix. Which is also wildly useful.

Also See:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186286/get-transformation-matrix-from-points

---

If you actually are *only* concerned with a affine matrix you can actually use the unit-square and simplify things. So if your corners go: (0,0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1) in affine space and you're mapping this to your points the equation is:

```
a = x4 - x1
b = x2 - x1
c = x1
d = y4 - y1
e = y2 - y1
f = y1
```

Keep in mind x3,y3 are never used. If we say this is an affine matrix then it doesn't matter the point absolutely must be located in the one given location because in affine space lines remain parallel. See: [Proof-Math](https://leanprover-community.github.io/lean-web-editor/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fgist.githubusercontent.com%2Ftatarize%2Fb17a367b0aef7151f4c25bad32a9bd17%2Fraw%2F9b713e6da3d95fde587f93d0a342bb58d45770ac%2Faffine.lean) for the proof these equations. You can map 8 points together (or rather 6 points really since affine doesn't need that last one), in the procedure given above.

If you add in,

```
  rw (by ring: x4 - x1 + (x2 - x1) + x1 = x4 - x1 + x2) at h5,
  rw (by ring: y4 - y1 + (y2 - y1) + y1 = y4 - y1 + y2) at h6,
  rw eq_comm at h6 h5,
```

After the bit it'll rewrite the final equations as:

```
h5 : x3 = x4 - x1 + x2,
h6 : y3 = y4 - y1 + y2
```

Which is essentially a requirement of the position of x3 and y3 for the goal to remain true. h5 and h6 are true iff space the space is affine.

---

Update:

I've since moved to a different set of equations for perspective. It uses points `(0,0)`, `(0,1)`, `(1,1)` and `(1,0)` and thus is simplified.:

```py
   def perspective(cls, p1, p2, p3, p4):
        x1, y1 = p1
        x2, y2 = p2
        x3, y3 = p3
        x4, y4 = p4

        i = 1
        try:
            j = (y1 - y2 + y3 - y4) / (y2 - y3)
            k = (x1 - x2 + x3 - x4) / (x4 - x3)
            m = (y4 - y3) / (y2 - y3)
            n = (x2 - x3) / (x4 - x3)

            h = i * (j - k * m) / (1 - m * n)
            g = i * (k - j * n) / (1 - m * n)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            h = 0.0
            g = 0.0

        c = x1 * i
        f = y1 * i
        a = x4 * (g + i) - x1 * i
        b = x2 * (h + i) - x1 * i
        d = y4 * (g + i) - y1 * i
        e = y2 * (h + i) - y1 * i

        return cls(a, d, b, e, c, f)
```

See proof: https://leanprover-community.github.io/lean-web-editor/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fgist.githubusercontent.com%2Ftatarize%2Ff4361ebdd563de07d76ec5cb5226122d%2Fraw%2F077066a6cecb785ad5c1d5a3d376b86b605e39ba%2Funitsquare.lean

Comment: The computation of g above lacks division by j as given in the linked math.stackexchange post

Comment: @adrock20 I can come to no other conclusion than you are simply right. It was not detected before as I used a lot of affine math where I expect that to be 0.

Comment: @adrock20 I also spent a while solving it for the unit square which gave me a much cleaner equation for the matrix there. Appended it to the end there.